# Algorithm for associating track ids

Tags: algorithms

Hello Computer Science stackexchange, I am trying to make an object tracking system. I have a module for object detections which feeds into a object tracking module. However, due to objects sometimes not getting detected and a greedy tracking algorithm the output of these two modules end up with 68 objects where the ground truth is only 23 and  an illustration of this can be seen in figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLU5q.png).

[image: Illustration of positions of every ID in each frame (Y-axis represents IDs and X-axis represents frame number]

First I tried to make a greedy algorithm which simply took the closest *start frame* to an ID's *last frame*. This gave some problems because sometimes two IDs would have the same *last frame* as their closest, which meant the first ID would get the association. I have also tried to introduce euclidean distance as a weight parameter, but the problem is still that I want to find the global best matches (I don't know the terminology) which can output 23 track ids instead of 68.

So my question is, what field of algorithms is this problem a part of and what do I search?

And how do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the problem isn't defined well enough.

## Update:

As previously mentioned the ID takes the closest *first frame* to the ID's *last frame*, an example of this can be seen in figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDChq.png). [image: ID 0 has these possibilities] Here it can be seen that ID 0 has 21 possible IDs to associate with, where it will take either ID 48, 49, 50 or 51 depending on how small the euclidean distance is. So imagine that ID 0 has the position [100,100] and the other IDs has (with distances to ID 0):

ID 48: [135,153] (63.51 pixels)
ID 49: [75, 50] (55.90 pixels)
ID 50: [531, 56] (433.24 pixels)
ID 51:  [352, 731] (679.46 pixels)

Here it would take ID 49 as it is the closest in distance.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Alas, I am having difficulty understanding the question.  I don't know what the graph represents (e.g., what the axes represent or what each bar represents).  I don't understand what your greedy algorithm is doing, or what you mean by "the closest start frame" or "an ID's last frame".  You ask how to solve this problem but I don't understand what problem you want to solve.

Comment: Oh sorry, I tried to make a caption for the image. The X-axis represents the frames and the Y-axis represents the IDs. I will update the question with further explanation.